# Find string in text file and set variable with windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, numbers, line

I have a file named `hdd_list.txt`.

```
Index: 0
Device Name: \Device\Harddisk0\Partition0
Drive: entire disk
Label: 
Type: Harddisk
Size: 55.899GB

Index: 1
Device Name: \Device\Harddisk0\Partition1
Drive: C:\
Label: 
Type: Harddisk
Size: 55.897GB

Index: 2
Device Name: \Device\Harddisk1\Partition0
Drive: entire disk
Label: 
Type: Harddisk
Size: 465.761GB

Index: 3
Device Name: \Device\Harddisk1\Partition1
Drive: E:\
Label: Backup
Type: Harddisk
Size: 465.758GB
```

I need to retrieve `Index` number corresponding to "c:\" and then subtract it minus 1 to get `Index` for the entire disk.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Try next *array-like* approach:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /A "ii=-1"
For /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=:" %%G in (
        "D:\bat\StackOverflow\files\30435794.txt") do (
    if /I "%%~G"=="Index" set /A "ii+=1"
    For /F "tokens=*" %%# in ("%%~H") do set "auxH=%%~#"
    set "__%%~G[!ii!]=!auxH!"

    if /I "!auxH!"=="C:\" set /A "__indexC=!ii!-1"

  )
set __ | findstr /I /L "[%__indexC%]"

ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

**Output**:

```
==>D:\bat\StackOverflow\30435794.bat
__Device Name[0]=\Device\Harddisk0\Partition0
__Drive[0]=entire disk
__Index[0]=0
__Size[0]=55.899GB
__Type[0]=Harddisk

==>
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "Index="
for /F "tokens=2" %%a in ('findstr "Index: Drive:" hdd_list.txt') do (
   if not defined Index (
      set /A Index=%%a-1
   ) else (
      if /I "%%a" equ "C:\" (
         goto diskFound
      ) else (
         set "Index="
      )
   )
)
:diskFound
echo The index for entire disk C:\ is: %Index%
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted... Nice script thanks :-).

Comment: May I ask you to select this one as best answer? You may also upvote it when you have enough rep to do so

Answer (score 0):

I would use [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) regular expression text processing utility that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
@echo off
for /f %%N in (
  'jrepl "Index: (\d+)\r?\n.*\nDrive: C:\\" "$1-1" /jmatch /m /f hdd_list.txt'
) do set "index=%%N"
```

I use the `/M` option to allow searches across multiple lines, and the `/JMATCH` option to only return matches, and to specify the replacement string as a JScript expression (subtract 1 from the value).

The search looks for the Index line, capturing the number, followed by any line, followed by the `Drive: C\` line.